# Set username as prefix in URIs Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I want to set prefix in all of the authenticated URIs in Laravel 5.3 app. If I use `Route::group(['prefix' => {username}])`, then how can I get the username in `web.php` file.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have defined routes like this:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '/{user}'], function() {
    Route::get('/profile', 'UserController@showProfile')->name('user.profile');
});
```

You can use Laravel's `route-model binding` to pass an `User` instance directly into your routes:

```
<a href="{{ route('user.profile', \Auth::user()->username) }}">View Profile</a>
```

Then in the `controller` , you can easily grab that model instance:

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
     public function showProfile(User $user)
    {
        return view('user.profile.index', compact('user'));
    }
}
```

Check out the documentation [here.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#route-model-binding)

**EDIT**:   By default, Laravel uses the `id` column when retrieving a given model class. You can change that to any column, in your case `username` , easily by overriding the `getRouteKeyName()` method on your `User` model.

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'username';
}
```

Comment: Won't work unless you change the RouteKeyName to point to the username instead of the default id. You should mention that.

Comment: I did link the documentation for that purpose, but I guess I'll add that anyway.

Comment: What if I want to do something like this `str_slug(Auth::user()->name)`, then how should I pass it to the URI?

Answer (score 0):

You can't and you shouldn't hardcore routes with usernames. If you have 100 users, do you plan to create 100 route groups for each user? Assuming each user has 2 routes that's 200 routes.

What you need to do is generate routes with username segment and detect the user on the fly based on the user name.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{username}'], function () {
    Route::get('profile', 'UserController@profile');
    Route::get('setting', 'UserController@setting');
});
```

The routes generated would be like

```
http://example.app/{username}/profile
http://example.app/{username}/setting
```

So a user with username `adam` with get the links.

```
http://example.app/adam/profile
http://example.app/adam/setting
```

Similarly you can have username based links for all your users and you need to detect them in your controller using route model binding or the standard way.

**Edit**

For closure based routes you can get the url segment like so

```
Route::get('{username}/profile', function ($username) {
    return 'Username is '.$username;
});
```

With controllers you get them as the parameters.

```
public function profile($username)
{
    return $username;
}
```

Comment: how do i get `adam` or any `{username}` in the `web.php` file?

Comment: @FahadIqbalAhmadKhan i've updated my answer. That give you an idea on how to retrieve the username from the route.

Comment: is there any short way to do that? I have more than 100 routes right now. It'll take a lot of time to pass a parameter to all the functions.

Comment: Doing so your whole route url is going to change. So of course you need to  make the necessary changes. There is no other way. For the controller methods/routes which don't necessarily need the username, you can skip from adding the parameter and it will be ignored.

Comment: What if I want to do something like this `str_slug(Auth::user()->name)``, then how should I pass it to the URI?

Comment: Doesn't matter, you can pass anything in place of `username` in the url. It depends on how you generate the url, you could use username or slugify it or pass id. Based on whatever you pass, you should be able to resolve the value back to a user.

Comment: Doesn't matter, you can pass anything in place of `username` in the url. It depends on how you generate the url, you could use username or slugify it or pass id. Based on whatever you pass, you should be able to resolve the value back to a user.

Comment: it's not working with either `compact` or `with` while passing it with `return view()`

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. Post some code in your question and then refer it when trying to describe the issue.